# Controller not working in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I am new to Angular JS. To see the working of controller, I implemented this simple code where two numbers are taken as an input from the users and their sum is calculated in the controller and the result is displayed in the view. But somehow it does not work. The code is as follows :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="CalculatorApp" ng-controller="CalculatorController">
<p> Number 1 <input type="number" ng-model="a"></p>
<p> Number 2 <input type="number" ng-model="b"></p>
<p> Addition is {{c}} </p>
</div>

angular.module('CalculatorApp', [])
.controller('CalculatorController', function($scope) 
{
$scope.c=$scope.a + $scope.b;
});

</body>
</html>
```

Please guide.

Comment: Yoiu forgot your script tags...

Answer (score 3):

You need to add JavaScript code in `script` tag with `type='text/javascript'`, so that while parsing the page desired JavaScript run.

And for getting the calculated result on HTML you should follow @chet answer.

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('CalculatorApp', [])
    .controller('CalculatorController', function($scope) {
         $scope.c = $scope.a + $scope.b; //should follow @chet answer
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you forgot to wrap your JavaScript in `<script></script>` tags. Even then you have a problem.

Change `Addition is {{c}}` to `Addition is {{a + b}}`, and drop the controller calculation altogether.

The code in the function defines the controller, it is not executed every time something changes.

Alternately, you could define a function on $scope, and then call the function.

```
$scope.calc = function() {
    return $scope.a + $scope.b;
};
```

Then change your HTML to `Addition is {{calc()}}`.

Comment: Got the script tags part.

Comment: Got the script tags part. Also know that the addition can be performed without the controller in the view. But just wanted to understand the working of the controller. Is the function necessary to do the addition in the controller.

Comment: Yes, you would have to define a function.

Comment: Any reasons for necessity of function in the controller. Can you elaborate ? Sorry for this as I am totally new to angular js

Comment: First, you don't need a function. You only need a function if you don't want to do the calculation in the view (this is reasonable, for example it may be more complicated than a + b, or simple separation of concerns). However, if you don't want it in the view then it needs to be calculated somewhere. You can't put it in the controller like you had it because it would only be run on initialization, not any time `a` or `b` changes. Another option is to place a watch on a and b such that changes to them modify another variable `c`. But my understanding is that placing watches is undesirable.

Comment: OK that means we have to place only the data (Model) into the controller and the bussiness logic has to be placed in the functions. Right?

Comment: You place both the model and business logic functions in the controller. What you don't do is execute logic in the controller initialization function.